# Where-Object cmdlet syntax

Tags: powershell, syntax

I'm trying to learn how to use [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) correctly in the below command-lines to display all processes larger than 20 megabytes.

```
get-process | Select-Object Name, @{Name="Private Memory (MB)"; Expression={$_.privatememorysize / 1mb}} |
    Where-Object {"Private Memory (MB)" -gt 20} |
    Sort-Object "Private Memory (MB)" -Descending |
    format-table -autosize
```

I am able to kind of do it in the below command-line. However, I don't want to specify it using *20971520 bytes*. I would rather like to specify it in megabytes. If that's not possible (or the command-line would get too complex), then I'd just like the output to show all processes larger than *20 MB*; even if I have to specify it using bytes:

```
get-process | Select-Object Name, @{Name="Private Memory (MB)"; Expression={$_.privatememorysize / 1mb}} |
    where-object {$_.privatememorysize -gt 20971520} |
    Sort-Object "Private Memory (MB)" -Descending |
    format-table -autosize
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
where-object {"Private Memory (MB)" -gt 20}
```

to

```
where-object {$_."Private Memory (MB)" -gt 20}
```

As in

```
get-process | 
    Select-Object Name, @{Name="Private Memory (MB)"; Expression={$_.privatememorysize / 1mb}} | 
    Where-Object {$_."Private Memory (MB)" -gt 20} | 
    Sort-Object "Private Memory (MB)" -Descending | 
    format-table -autosize
```

The reason you can just use 20 (vs 20mb) in your Where-Object expression is because you already specified the unit of measure in your select statement. In fact, if you use 20971520, it will think you mean 20971520 MB.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify sizes literally in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> 1KB
1024
PS C:\> 1MB
1048576
PS C:\> 1GB
1073741824
```

So you can use those literally in your code when you want to perform a mathematical operation. So if all you wanted to do was to replace that literal, go for it:

```
$myProcesses = get-process | 
where-object { $_.privatememorysize -gt 20MB } | 
select-object name, @{ Name = "Private Memory (MB)"; Expression = {$_.privatememorysize / 1MB}} |
Sort-object "Private Memory (MB)" -Descending
```

A note: you'll probably only want to use `format-table` on an object when it is ready to be output to be read by a user.  So in this case, once you're ready to output this to the screen you could simply do `$myProcesses | format-table -autosize`.  If you're doing this from the command line and simply want to see the results ASAP, then don't even bother with the variable and format it like you described.

Comment: I was just about to post nearly the exact same code. I just took too long to test it to make sure it was right :)

Comment: @alroc Aw, that's a bummer.  I appreciate you taking the time to edit the OP though.  Thanks for helping to improve posts on the powershell tag!